# Why is my app getting stuck on navigation

Tags: django, angular, router

I have a route in my Angular app that is **/service-categories**. Here's the ngOnInit to the component that is loaded on that route:

```
ngOnInit() {

this.apiDataService.readData(env.routes.services.getServiceCategories, false, 'get').subscribe(response => {
  this.serviceCategories = response.data.map(serviceCategory => new ServiceCategory(serviceCategory));
  });
}
```

Here's the API view in Django REST Framework that gets those service categories:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def service_categories(request):

try:

    serviceCategories = ServiceCategory.objects.all()
    serializer = ServiceCategorySerializer(serviceCategories, many=True)

    return generic_data_response(serializer.data)

except:

    return generic_internal_server_error_response()
```

Everything works fine until I log in using Facebook. The route is **/login** and here is the code that handles that:

```
this.socialAuthService.authState.pipe(
  switchMap((user: SocialUser) => {
    if (user && user.authToken) {
      this.socialUser = user;
      return this.authService.convertToken(user.provider.toLowerCase(), user.authToken)
    } else {
      return throwError(new Error('An unexpected error occurred.'));
    }
  })
).subscribe((res) => {
  if (res.status === 200) {
    localStorage.setItem('__bn_api_current_user', JSON.stringify(this.socialUser));
    localStorage.setItem('__bn_api_access', res.body.access_token);
    localStorage.setItem('__bn_api_refresh', res.body.refresh_token);
    this.router.navigate(['service-categories']);
  }
});
```

localStorage is updated just fine but, upon navigating to **service-categories**, the application hangs. I can see the call to the API to get the service categories, and it goes into a pending state and just waits and waits until the app crashes.

Comment: I guess the causes will be there in which you are not providing in your question.

Comment: The method that calls the API needs to resolve / reject the `Promise`. Does it do that properly?